# How to specify Log10 bin height scale in GeoHistogram function?

Tags: histograms, geographics

I have some data that is heavy tailed (density of geocoded entities), and I want to use the `GeoHistogram` function to plot it, but with a log scale. Data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j4np8cvkp1c33hn/AAD7yB-emov3xUENyAHlj7TSa?dl=0).

When plotted normally, the graph looks like this:

```
geoState = WolframAlpha["state of New York", "Result"];

Show[
 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap"],GeoStyling[Lighter[Orange, 0.5]],
   Opacity[0.05],EdgeForm[{Thin,Gray}],Polygon[geoState]}, 
   GeoScaleBar -> "Miles"], 
 GeoHistogram[geoData,600 sq mi, GeoBackground -> None, 
   GeoRangePadding -> 150 Quantity[1, "Kilometers"], 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
]
```

[image]

I would like a `Log10` scale for the bin height (*hspec*).  The function description for `GeoHistogram` says that the format `GeoHistogram[*data, bspec, hspec]*` should work. I can't seem to find the proper format for *hspec* to get log-scaled bin heights.

I have tried `"Log",`, `{"Log", 20}`, and `Log10[#]&` with no joy.  The documentation lists the syntax as `GeoHistogram[*locs*,*bspec*,*hspec*]` with the following options for `*hspec*`:  "Count", "probability", "Intensity", "PDF", and *fh*, but does not specify the form of *fh*.  Taking an example from `Histogram` and defining `fh[bins_,counts_]:=Log10[counts_]` does not work either.  Unlike the `Histogram` function, the `GeoHistogram` *hspec* documentation does not list the form of {"Log",hspec} or option of "LogCounts".

Comment: I think this is a bug.

Comment: Is it sufficient to have them colored appropriately?

Comment: They should be colored appropriately and the scale bar labeled correctly.

Comment: Please provide sample data for `geoState` and `geoData`.

Comment: My reading of the documentation is that hspec takes two arguments.  You might try something like `Log10[#2] &` or `Log10[Last@#] &`

Comment: There is a pdf option so you might try the logarithmic distribution or some variation of it.

Comment: See the above edited question.  A link to the data (too large to post here) and the code for `geoState` is provided.

Comment: I can't find the hspec documentation you are referring to.  Both `Log10[#2] &` and' Log10[Last@#] &' return the error `GeoHistogram::hspec: Log10[Last[#1]]& is not a valid density specification`.

Comment: See the "Details and Options" section of the `GeoHistorgram` documentation for "The function fh in GeoHistogram[data,bspec,fh] is applied to two arguments: a list of bins {Subscript[reg, 1],Subscript[reg, 2],\[Ellipsis]} and the corresponding list of counts {Subscript[c, 1],Subscript[c, 2],\[Ellipsis]}. The function should return a list of densities to be used for each of the Subscript[c, ij]."  I agree that neither of my suggestions works.  `GeoHistogram` rejects them immediately and continues along to produce the same result it would have without the function.

Comment: In contrast, `fh1[reg_, c_] := Log10[c]` is called repeatedly, indicating that it is recognizable to `GeoHistogram` but does not produce the expected output.  I have run `Trace` on `GeoHistogram` with `fh1`, producing prodigious output but no insights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but you may be able to get what you want down this path. Instead of taking the `Log10` of the data I'll try to change the color scale via the `ColorFunction`

The base for the color function

```
Clear[cf]
cf[x_, min_, max_] := (Log10[x] - Log10[min])/(
 Log10[max] - Log10[min]);
```

I use the function with the `ColorFunction` option

```
min = 1;
max = 2000;
steps = Round[10^#  & /@ Subdivide[Log10[min], Log10[2 max], 10]];
obj = GeoHistogram[geoData, Quantity[600, ("Miles")^2], 
GeoBackground -> None, 
GeoRangePadding -> 150 Quantity[1, "Kilometers"],
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][cf[z, min, max]]],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{
 Function[{z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][cf[z, min, max]]], {min,
  max}},
  steps]]
```

[image]

You will want to play with the `min` and `max` values and possibly hand edit your steps for the scale.

Comment: Very close!  I still would like the scale to be something like {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000} and log spaced.  I am also trying to check that the color bar scaling reflects the bin values. Hard, since I can't extract the actual bin counts from the graph.

Comment: You can hand edit the `steps` array to have whatever numbers you want. To validate you can use the color scale "Rainbow" and check the popup numbers against the scale.

Answer (score 4):

Modification of [c186282](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4515/c186282)'s answer that shows Log10 scaling, with custom step intervals given, intermediate tics, and use of `Blend` to specify custom color function.

```
geoState = WolframAlpha["state of New York", "Result"];

cf3 = Function[{z}, 
      Blend[{Lighter[Blue, 0.9], Lighter[Blue, 0.6], Red, Yellow}, 
      cf[z, min, max]]];

decades = 4;
min = 1;
max = 10^decades;

steps = Sort[Flatten[{#* 10^Range[min - 1, decades] & /@ {1, 5}}]];

plt = GeoHistogram[geoData, Quantity[600, ("Miles")^2], "Count", 
       GeoBackground -> None, 
       GeoRangePadding -> 150 Quantity[1, "Kilometers"], 
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> cf3, 
       PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf3, {min, max}}, steps]];

Show[GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], GeoStyling[White], 
       EdgeForm[{Black, Gray}], Polygon[geoState]}, 
      GeoScaleBar -> "Miles"], plt]
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

I have verified that this is working with "Counts".  If you change to another geo-bin value (e.g. "Intensity"), the color scale {min,max} needs to be re-calibrated.

So, the bounty goes to [c186282](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4515/c186282).  Many thanks!